# Applescript throws error when changing file name

Tags: file, applescript

I am trying to create a generic temp .pdf and then change the file name of thetemp file to the specific file name in the same folder on an NAS drive using the code below.

I get error -10006 'can't change name of file...". Any help would be most appreciated.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
save active workbook in ("Volumes:FrameNASfolder:12 PANDORA:Pandora PDFs:PDF
    TempFolder:TempName.pdf") as PDF file format
end tell

tell application "Finder"
set name of "Volumes:FrameNASfolder:12 PANDORA:Pandora PDFs:PDF
 TempFolder:TempName Invoice + Quotation Sheet.pdf" to "3999A Estimate TEST 14-07-20 16-32.pdf"
end tell
```

I can generate the temp file every time, but no joy with the name change.

Comment: You are trying to change the name of a _string_ - try using a _file_.

Answer (score 0):

First of all – even if the *pseudo POSIX syntax* works – HFS paths are supposed to start with a disk name, not with `Users` nor with `Volumes`.

As mentioned in the comments you are going to change the file name of a string which is pretty pointless. Add the keyword `file`, `item` or `alias` to create a file system reference

```
set tempFolderPath to "FrameNASfolder:12 PANDORA:Pandora PDFs:PDF TempFolder:"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    save active workbook in (tempFolderPath & "TempName.pdf") as PDF file format
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    set name of file (tempFolderPath & "TempName Invoice + Quotation Sheet.pdf") to "3999A Estimate TEST 14-07-20 16-32.pdf"
end tell
```